# How to get important flag from Java Mail client

Tags: jakarta-mail

Is there a way to get whether a mail is marked as important or not from Java Mail API.? I'm using a Gmail account to connect. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different mailers use different ways to indicate that a message is "important".  Some use an X-Priority header.  Others use an Importance header.  I don't know offhand what Gmail uses, but look at the raw headers of a message and you should be able to figure it out.  Then use the JavaMail getHeader method to access that header.

Comment: `String priority = msg.getHeader("X-Priority", ""); if (priority != null && priority.equals("1")) ... // it's important`  Similarly for the more standard, but less used, [Importance and Priority headers](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/ietf-822/current/msg05603.html).

Comment: Thanks Sir, What is the type of "msg" and does it work when I set header "X-Priority", "1"?

Comment: msg is a MimeMessage.  Yes, you can set the X-priority header.